# how to get worker id when I enqueue a new work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

How can I delete the enqueued task?

Is there any returned id I can get when I enqueue a new task ?

And I can remove the enqueued task by what method ?

Thanks

I append my work to queue `Resque.enqueue(StreamingVerificationWorker, @streaming_verification.id, @settings)`

### streaming_verification_worker.rb

```
class StreamingVerificationWorker
  @queue = :automation
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the gem [resque status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status). In any case, I moved from resque to sidekiq a couple of years ago and haven't looked back since then. Sidekiq in my opinion is superior to resque, while compatible in the redis queue.